# add a LXD Host on MAAS

Tags: maas, lxd

this is my lab:

- 1 SVR IBM system x3650 M4 with Ubuntu 18.04 and MAAS
- 2 SVR IBM system x3650 M4 with Ubuntu 18.04 as hypervisor

Installing KVM and virt on NODEs I can manage the VM via MAAS, if I want to use LXD for creating the VM and manage them on MAAS, is there a way to make that? 
I'd like use LXD as hypervisor on my NODEs
thanks

Comment: Just keep in mind, LXD is not a hypervisor, it's containerization, not virtualization.

Comment: but KVM and LXD can work together? Can I use KVM to add the NODE on MAAS and use LXD to create a container? thanks